# Bash variable expansion on tab complete

Tags: bash, readline, bash-completion

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, and I'm seeing some odd behaviour when I try to use tab-completion in bash on a path that starts with a variable.  If I've got TOP=/scratch, and I try to tab-complete:

cd $TOP/foo

it changes to:

cd \$TOP/foo

I'd prefer it to complete to:
cd $TOP/foobar
or
cd /scratch/foobar
but I'd settle for it just not changing the line and requiring me to un-escape the $.

Does anyone know where in bash/readline I should look to fix this?

Comment: another workaround: use <Esc>+<Ctrl>-E or  <Ctrl><Alt>-E to expand the var.

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/41891/bash-auto-complete-for-environment-variables][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41891/bash-auto-complete-for-environment-variables

Comment: My workaround is this: `sudo yum remove bash-completion`. Tab complete still works but just [isn't as customizable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22854940/1888983). Importantly, paths in variables don't expand and remain as variables after hitting tab.

Comment: I’m running on Centos 8 and I see the same annoying behaviour. It was fine on Centos 6. And this is in 2020.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found the bug report, please register (if not already registered) and add yourself to the 'people affected' list, I just did:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627

#### Workarounds

Try enabling `direxpand` or `cdable_vars`:

```
shopt -s direxpand
# or
shopt -s cdable_vars
```

Apparently [<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> might be a workaround](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-auto-complete-of-environment-variables-613203/#post3023856):

> I haven't found a proper solution to this, but there's a workaround. The escaping of environment variables can be disabled by pressing Esc followed by tab.
>
> ```
> # cd $SO + [Esc] + [Tab]
> # cd $SOME_DIR
> ```

---

<sub>Confirm that as a bug! I just confirmed that the same thing works on</sub>

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10
Release:        10.10
Codename:       maverick
```

I get broken behaviour on (up-to-date) natty:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
Codename:   natty
```

Although I must add that I do *not* the slash escaped, but the path (while valid, existing, accessible and readable) is not getting expanded.

Info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 15):

The bug report refered to in other answers at [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627) gives a new workaround by issuing the command:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

It works for me.

Comment: How does this work for you, I don't see any different in behavior with it set or unset?  ESC-^E does expand the var in place for me which helps.  I'm on Bash 4.2.25

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem in cygwin (NT-6.1 2.0.1 2015-04-30) bash (GNU 4.3.33), especially when I would try to tab-expand a path that contained spaces.

I put `shopt -s direxpand` in my ~/.bashrc. Problem solved.