# Specifying two file extensions in bash complete

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I am trying to modify bash complete properties.

I can exclude a file extension for a command thusly:

```
complete -f -X '*hi' vim
```

I want to specify two file names for exclusion. How do I do this?

Note: the following command did not work.

```
complete -f -X '(*hi|*o)' vim
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to turn on *Extended Globs*. Run this at the command line, or add it to your .bashrc to make it permanent:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Now, your complete command can look like this:

```
complete -f -X '*.@(hi|o)' vim
```

Quoting from *Extended Globs* in [patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns):

```
@(list): Matches one of the given patterns.
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, although it's the same as all the other examples out there. Pasted verbatim and bash 4.3.30 still completes `.o` files. Works fine when giving a single extension though.

Comment: For this to work, the `bash-completion` package must be installed and probably sourced via `/etc/bashrc` in your `~/.bashrc`. However I've uninstalled mine as it breaks proper [expansion of environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418493/bash-variable-expansion-on-tab-complete) such as `ls $DIR/somefil<tab>`.